# Resillence4J for SpringBoot - CLOSE Circuit

Tags: spring-boot, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

I am using resilience4j for implementing Circuit breaker in my spring boot application. In this one I am getting  `POST /actuator/circuitbreakers/{name}` endpoint from which I can close the circuit. I am deploying this service on kubernetes which has 3 pads. However what will happen when i call this api and request only closes circuit breaker in 1 pod. I assume that it will only affect the circuit breaker state within that specific pod.

If this is the case then how can I implement a mechanism for sharing and synchronizing the circuit breaker state across pods ?